# Microsoft BotBuilder node.js : How to send formatted text (BOLD , Italic , New Line ) to Android Skype for business client from Bot

Tags: node.js, botframework, skype-for-business

We have implemented a Bot using Microsoft BotBuilder in node js, to proactively send message to Skype for Business users. We have requirement to send few formatted text such as - Bold, Italic , and line break (new Line), But It seems that Android Skype for business doesn't support any of these format. All Html formatted is shown as Raw HTML in all platforms (iOS, Android and MAC).
So far we have tried following ways to send Formatted text.

```
//1 using \n\n
var msgToSend = new builder.Message()
                            .text("Hello \n\n World!");
//2 using unicodes
var msgToSend = new builder.Message()
                            .text("Hello \u0085 \u2028 World!");
//using html formatting
var msgToSend = new builder.Message()
                            .text("Hello </br> World!");


bot.loadSession(addr1, function (err, session) {
    bot.send(msgToSend);
});
```

We succeeded to send new line text to Mac, iOS, and Windows Skype for Business clients, but None of these seems to work for Android.
Any help would be appreciated to send formatted text to android.

Answer (score 2):

As already replied in a question around the same theme (which was about webchat and rendering HTML):

Microsoft Bot Framework supports only 2 types of text format (see documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-channel-inspector?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#text-formatting)):

- **Markdown**
- **XML** (The textFormat xml is supported only by the Skype channel.)

As a consequence:

- HTML will not help you here
- you are limited to the capabilities of markdown and the restrictions of markdown rendering in your channel

If you look at markdown for `Skype for Business` in [Channel Inspector](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/channel-inspector/channels/SkypeForBusiness?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365&f=Markdown&e=example1), there is no possibility to do what you want (bold, italic etc. are not rendered as wished), sorry

[image]

Comment: Yes , you are right. Microsoft Bot Framework supports only 2 types of text format . 
But there are some unicodes which work for atleast **new line** .
like - \u0085 , \u2028 , \u2029
these unicodes works on Windows, MAc and iOS , but not on Android.

Comment: I would like to know if there are any unicodes which works on all these mentioned platforms.

Comment: I don't know. Did you try carriage return (\u000D)?

Comment: Yes , and that don't help :(

Comment: "  \n \n"  :-  two spaces + \n + space . This worked for me!

Comment: Good to know, really strange as "\n\n" without spaces is enough for example for the Webchat channel

Comment: @Planet-Zoom Any luck mate ?

Comment: Unfortunately no...we had to quit it after having meeting with microsoft product teams , concluding that it is not going to be resolved...